# how to get the column index of the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two image buttons in the GridView used for selection. They populate the textboxes. What I need is when i click imagebutton "Edit" it should populate the textboxes from the gridview and when the imagebutton "Delete" is pressed it does the same and disbale the textboxes too. The point is am not getting a logic of how to get the column indexes programmatically.
help me out with the condition.
the issue is just with the c# code. Here is the snippet which i have tried:

```
  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

            if (condition)
            {
                _PropertyTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                _Address.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                _PropertyTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                _PropertyTitle.Enabled = false;
                _Address.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                _Address.Enabled = false;
            }
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: i am not getting what logic to put in the condition...

Comment: what code should i try to get the column index

Comment: Column-index from what?

Comment: column index of the imagebuttons because both the button will have different funcationalities.

Comment: But the code that you are showing does not handle an `ImageButton`'s click-event but the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event of the `GridView`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter should i put the screenshot in the question..??

Comment: actually i have enabled selection on the gridview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64780/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-haider-khattak).

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from question that what you are trying to achieve.But what i got is you want to write specify both image button click separately.

for that you have to use the RowCommand event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

In this row command event according to CommandName (of button) you can manage the code for two buttons

Refer this link for Rowcommand event [row command](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click)
[One more link](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/67/Aspnet-Grid-view-Row-command-Event.aspx)